# C# Split namevaluepair string with delimitter in values using regex

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I have a string

> "FirstName=John, LastName=Smith, Address=1 Wall Street, NY"

which needs to be split into a dictionary as:

- {"FirstName", "John"}
- {"LastName", "Smith"}
- {"Address", "1 Wall Street, NY"}

How can this be achieved using `Regex` considering Address field value has the delimiter `','` in it?

Also lets say I have the following string (note the colon in Address):

> "FirstName=John, LastName=Smith, Address:1 Wall Street, NY"

How can the above mentioned result be with either `= or :` acting as the key value pair separator?

Comment: wouldn't it be easier with C# instead of regex

Comment: if "," is allowed as both separator and text, and you dont have the proper opening/closing "quotes" for literals then....chances are this is not possible or really hard to parse

Comment: @qamar note that "," is allowed in literals..if you do a split(','...) then...it would fail LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming keys cannot contain any of delimeters (comma should be followed by key to separate pairs)

```
var data = "FirstName=John, LastName=Smith, Address:1 Wall Street, NY, USA, TestKey=TestValue";
var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var reg = @"([^=:,]*)[=:](.*?)(?:$|,\s*(?=[^=:,]*[=:]))";
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(data, reg)) {
    var key = m.Groups[1].Value;
    var val = m.Groups[2].Value;
    dic[key] = val;
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", key, val);
}
```